# How do i get the color of a pixel from a WriteableBitmap?

Tags: c#, uwp, pixel, writeablebitmap

I tried everything, but the WriteableBitmap class just doesn't have the .CopyPixels() method like it is said in the droumentation:https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Example of what Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 underlines red:

```
 writeableBitmap.CopyPixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, 20, 10),pixels, 20 * 4, 0);
```

Comment: It works fine in my environment. Have you included a reference to PresentationCore. dll ?

Comment: Now...Yes, and there was a second reason why it didn't work . I used "using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;" instead of "using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;". Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, what you want is the [WriteableBitmap class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) in **UWP**. However, the document you've referenced is the [WriteableBitmap Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) in **.NET Framework**, which is used in traditional desktop apps. For matching document, please see [**WriteableBitmap class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx).

And for the the `WriteableBitmap class` in UWP, we can use [WriteableBitmap.PixelBuffer property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.pixelbuffer.aspx) to get the pixels from a `WriteableBitmap` like:

```
byte[] pixels = writeableBitmap.PixelBuffer.ToArray();
```

For more info, please see [XAML images sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/0f5d56ae-5e57-48e1-9cd9-993115b027b9). Although this is a Windows 8.1 Store app, but it's the same in UWP apps.

Comment: I tried this solution but I get an error: `Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source`. Maybe you have an idea of the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39817619/converting-a-writeablebitmap-image-toarray-in-uwp